# Looping back after condition is false

Tags: c#

```
int userSelection;
string userInput;
Console.WriteLine("Welcome! Please make a selection by Entering 1, 2, 2 or 4");
DisplayMenuOptions();
userSelection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while (userSelection >= 1 && userSelection <= 4)
{
if (userSelection == 1)
{
    // CODES FOR FULL FILE LISTING"
}
else if (userSelection == 2)
{
    // CODES FOR FILTERED FILE LISTING"
}
else if (userSelection == 3)
{
    // CODES FOR DISPLAY FOLDER STATISTICS"
}
else if (userSelection == 4) //code that will be executed every time user select 4
{
    // CODES TO QUIT"
}
else 
{
     Console.WriteLine("ERROR MESSAGE HERE");
}
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue"); //waits for user to press enter
Console.ReadKey(); //reads user keystroke
Console.Clear(); //clears display information
DisplayMenuOptions();
userSelection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //reads and converts user selection
}
```

but it quits the application instead of waiting for user to input again.

I am a beginner at programming and this is my first attempt at any Console C# Application. It is part of my assignment. Therefore if there is anything I am doing wrong here please guide me.

When I place it outside of the while loop it only executes once when user enters invalid input but it quits the second time the user enters invalid output.

Thank you

Comment: Please show where userSelection is being initialize and assigned a value, and the current code.

Comment: They are initialised at the beginning

Comment: @Yasin No problem with editing out the unecessary code blocks, but you switched an && and an || in your edit, and removed the initialization code, so I changed those back. If the first one was an error, feel free to change it back. The second provides context, and makes the question more complete, so it should probably remain. Thank you for making a constructive edit this time.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yea, this was the original code, except for the break; part so I edited that out. Thank you, I understand people will benefit from this in the future so I converted it to the original post instead of extensive and irrelevant codes I posted after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's what your while loop says: *"loop while the input is between 1 and 4"* , which becomes false when the user enters invalid input.

Given you only want to exit when the input equals four, nothing else:

```
while (userSelection != 4)
```

Then you can restore the `} else {` too, as that did work as intended.

Comment: Oh Thank you, I understand what I am doing wrong now! Thanks!

Comment: Yep, It works now. The application displays the message every time user enters invalid input

Comment: You may want to test that with non-numeric input though.

Comment: Yea, I dont know how to do that so I am doing a bit of research... Going through lecture notes does no give any hints as to how

Comment: @Yasin Look at the `TryParse` family of functions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `while` condition prevents the loop from being entered when the selection is invalid.

You need to remove this behavior if you want to detect invalid values inside the loop.

```
while (true)
{
    if (userSelection == 1)
    {
        // CODES FOR FULL FILE LISTING"
    }
    else if (userSelection == 2)
    {
        // CODES FOR FILTERED FILE LISTING"
    }
    else if (userSelection == 3)
    {
        // CODES FOR DISPLAY FOLDER STATISTICS"
    }
    else if (userSelection == 4) //code that will be executed every time user select 4
    {
        // CODES TO QUIT"
    }
    else 
    {
         Console.WriteLine("ERROR MESSAGE HERE");
         break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue"); //waits for user to press enter
    Console.ReadKey(); //reads user keystroke
    Console.Clear(); //clears display information
    DisplayMenuOptions();
    userSelection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //reads and converts user selection
}
```

Comment: No, you can add break if you want the loop to exist when that code is executed (as it would be in your initial code). But what I'm showing you is how to detect the condition within the loop. I can't tell you what the code there should do. It's your code.

Comment: @Yasin: How did you determine that it does not display the error message just prior to quitting? I believe my code is correct, and the statements in the `else` condition are executed when the selection is less than 1 or greater than 4. Please do not turn this into a discussion about what that code should do. I have no idea what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: I ran the code, entered invalid input and pressed enter thats how. Okay... Thank you anyway... The error code is supposed to continuously display until the user enters valid input.... Just saying. Thanks Anyway

Comment: No it isn't. If it displayed a message and then exited immediately, it might be very difficult to see whether or not it displayed the message. So I can ask again: how did you determine that the message was not being  displayed?

Comment: Since the writeline code is there I suppose it does display the message. Which means I determined wrong

Comment: Right, and so I have answered the question that you asked.

Comment: Okay, Thanks Although the question was how to loop back after displaying the code. I have already achieved displaying the code